# Program and debugger quit without indication of problem

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm developing a WPF application. When debugging, the logic reaches a certain point, then the application quits for no reason. VS debugger catches nothing and the only indication of a problem is the following in the output window:

> The program '[6228] SomeApp.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f).

When debugging the release version, or indeed running the debug build out of the debugger (in fact all combos that aren't running the debug version in debugger), everything works fine.

I'm trying to catch unhandled exceptions with the following code:

```
        AppDomain
            .CurrentDomain
            .UnhandledException +=
            (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unhandled Exception " + e.ExceptionObject);
            };
        Application
            .Current
            .DispatcherUnhandledException +=
            (sender1, e1) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DispatcherUnhandledException " + e1.Exception);
            };
```

...but I'm not catching anything.

I'm considering peppering the app with debug output statements, but it's highly asynchronous so reading this will be both arduous and tedious.

How do I start figuring what is going on?

Comment: First thing you could try is to turn on Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Enable Debuggers -> Enable unmanaged code debugging.  That might produce more information in the output window.  Also catch all exceptions (CLR, C++, structured) when thrown in Debug -> Exceptions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to ntstatus.h file, 0x4000001f (STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT) is an exception status code that is used by the Win32 x86 emulation subsystem. It (I suppose) means that you reached a breakpoint which  is not exploitable. You should enable debugging unmanaged code.

Comment: Sounds promising. I'm using naudio which calls out to dsound.dll so this is a good lead.

Comment: This worked for myself - as I was getting the same error, many thanks Vladimir.

Answer (score 13):

Using Visual Studio 2012 (Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL), the only solution I found was to go to Project -> Properties -> Debug and turn off "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".

The option "Enable native code debugging" did not help even though I had all exceptions set to break-when-thrown.

Interestingly, this problem only started happening when I upgraded from VS2012 beta to the VS2012 official release.

Answer (score 7):

I Have the same Situation with Visual Studio 2013.
Like Ron This save My day :
Project -> Properties -> Debug and turn off "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved me a lot of time... I was calling an old style C dll from a C# project (x86) and I was having this problem. Doing that I've been able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting fixed the problem for me.

I encountered the problem attempting to debug through NUnit via Resharper's test runner, and separately attempting to step through a W3WP.exe process.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same behavior with FonstSize="auto" (not sure why):

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" FontSize="auto"/>`

Fix:`<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />`

Additional Error Output:

> LS stop assert - tserrInternalError, file
>   f:\dd\wpf\src\native\ums\shared\inci\tsoverflow.h, line 66
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in PresentationCore.dll 
>   Additional information: Vom Textformatierungsmodul kann aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers keine Textzeile formatiert werden: "LsInternalError".

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem . in my case I noted I had a property with getter and setters . My mistake was to return the property itself instead of the attributed linked to it, and this was forcing the debugger to go to an infinite loop , after fixing , the problem was solved . I was getting the same error code with no additional info-