# vshost32.exe has stopped working when I call the ShowDialog method of OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, vshost.exe

I've a c# application, I'm doing a final test of it.

But now, a function which has worked everytimes until now doesn't work anymore!

I've a Button, when I click on it I want to browse files, I see the "Open file" windows, and an half second after, I got an uncaught visual studio error:

vshost32.exe has stopped working:

I'm sorry but the error is happening on a french localized computer:

```
Signature du problème :
  Nom d’événement de problème:  APPCRASH
  Nom de l’application: TOM.vshost.exe
  Version de l’application: 10.0.30319.1
  Horodatage de l’application:  4ba2084b
  Nom du module par défaut: ntdll.dll
  Version du module par défaut: 6.1.7600.16695
  Horodateur du module par défaut:  4cc7ab44
  Code de l’exception:  c0000008
  Décalage de l’exception:  0004631f
  Version du système:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:   4108
  Information supplémentaire n° 1:  ffb6
  Information supplémentaire n° 2:  ffb61531feaa1f65f528a2694a510c22
  Information supplémentaire n° 3:  b220
  Information supplémentaire n° 4:  b2205da238309b0a025a25162a3a18f3
```

My code is:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog {Filter = Filters};
if (ofd.ShowDialog() != true) {
    return;
}
```

it crash just when I'm in the ofd.ShowDialog.

Is this a code related issue?

Do you have any idea about how to debug? Or even how to debug this??

When activating the "unmanaged code to be debug", I got this:

```
"First-chance exception at 0x77cd631f in TOM.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified."
```

The stack trace if it could help:

```
>   ntdll.dll!77cd631f()    
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    ntdll.dll!77d1792d()    
    ntdll.dll!77ce343b()    
    ntdll.dll!77ce2d80()    
    ole32.dll!776b4102()    
    ole32.dll!776b411e()    
    ole32.dll!7767e505()    
    SearchFolder.dll!1046b49d()     
    SearchFolder.dll!1046b267()     
    shell32.dll!76281cb7()  
    shell32.dll!761701b6()  
    shell32.dll!761991fd()  
    shell32.dll!761d61ee()  
    shell32.dll!761d6159()  
    System.ni.dll!524c4ed4()    
    shlwapi.dll!77b6b6cf()  
    ntdll.dll!77cbb428()    
    ntdll.dll!77cbe6f9()    
    kernel32.dll!77c01114()     
    ntdll.dll!77ceb429()    
    ntdll.dll!77ceb3fc()
```

Some things I've tried:

**An important new point**:  It seems that the error doesn't happen when I run it without visual studio(which seems to be logic)

**Important point bis**: It seems the same code is working in visual studio of another computer(which is exactly the same and issued of the same image of windows

I tried to remove all files and do a GetLatest, but still doesn't work

Comment: A colleague of mine had the same problem not long ago (but with WinForms, not WPF, btw). Still looking for a solution, too...

Comment: Hi - don't think that this is code related (the code is rather simple) - maybe the "Filters" (what happens if you strip these?). Have you tried the "usual suspect" (reboot windows)? I don't understand france but I think the ntdll.dll is a rather low-level dll not directly linked to .net at all - so there should be a problem with your windows-instance I guess.

Comment: You could also try disabling the VS hosting functionality, at least until your next reboot (right click on the project -> properties -> debugging -> enable VS hosting process).

Comment: I have already restarted visual studio, I will test to restart the computer in few minutes.
I already tried to disable the VS hosting process, didn't changed anything

Comment: Restart doesn't change anything :(

Comment: It's unfortunate you never found a solution, I'm having this exact issue right now :| I have every exception enabled in the "debug-->exceptions" dialog, but it's not breaking, it just crashes.  I tried cleaning, manually deleting bin/obj folders, restarting VS/computer, everything... but it's still crashing (but only when the debugger is attached).  I also tried reverting to several old versions that I *know* open-file/save-file were working on while debugging, and those don't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just re-installed the image of this computer that have I done after the installation and now it works :/. Very strange

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same problem and my solution was to "Enable native code debugging" in "Project properties/Debug/Enable Debuggers" section.

I thought, that I should be able to debug the issue, but instead the error was gone.

Comment: Enabling native code debugging fixed my problem. Now the question is, why.

Comment: This works while debugging in Visual Studio. How it reflect in set up and deployment project.

Answer (score 4):

An possible this is a bug linked to Wuala Overlay Shell Extension.
Uninstalling help me.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/a073bbb8-5586-4f75-970f-858d90e069ef/openfiledialogsavefiledialog-crashen?forum=wpfde

Comment: I don't remember, but it's possible that I had wuala installed at this time. So it's possible solution

Comment: THANK YOU !! ... it's been three days i am scratching my head (and banging it on the wall), trying to know why my simple .showdialog() was systematically crashing when running in VS (and not when simply executing the .exe). I tried several answers all around this problem (calling it in a new thread with STA, switching from VB to C# to have better access to the 'main' function, deleting old dlls,  ... all to no avail. Then I saw your comment about Wuala, uninstalled it ... and now it works :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue that drove me crazy for a few days. It ended up being Lenovo Password Manager that came pre-installed on my laptop. It overlays forms with password boxes in with a remember password banner. Since uninstalling I've not encountered the issue again.

My suggestion to anyone coming across this is to check if you have any software that does any overlaying at all and check to see if that is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing something akin to this on a computer with German locale, with our French application. I can't remember how we solved it, but the similarity points me towards checking locales...
Invalid handle though usually means the object you call is already destroyed, though I really can't guess which object, as ofd must still be valid at this point.

Comment: I don't think so, because this project has worked during more than 10month on this computer and on another computer with french locales(and it still works without visual studio)

Comment: Could by any chance be an issue with using Debug mode and a non-debug dll? "No symbols loaded" and "doesn't crash without Visual Studio" gives a hint for that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem with "VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" in a VB project. In the menu DEBUG -> Exceptions... there has been an item checked. After a "Reset All" in that dialog (unchecking all) the problem disappeared once, but came again the next time. There was a 0x4000001f, so I found [Program and debugger quit without indication of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532457/program-and-debugger-quit-without-indication-of-problem). The given tip was helping again only onec: Project -> Properties -> Debug and turn **off** "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process". Later the problem occurred again!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem My exception code is c0020001. I solved this issue by resetting all exceptions. For that go to {Debug --> Exceptions} and there you can reset all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was adding new debug method. Instead of **AnyCPU** I used **x86** debugging (next to **"Start"** button above click **Configuration Manager -> Platform -> New -> x86** ). In meantime I have also enabled **ClickOnce security settings** in Project Properities, to **"This is full trust app"** but don't know the impact. Hope this will help somone.

Answer (score 0):

Add a key "Auto" of type REG_SZ into the registry under the location HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug and set to zero.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/configuring-automatic-debugging

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).