# CL.exe crashes in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cl.exe

I installed Visual Studio 2012 recently and it appears that I'm unable to build my solutions properly as the IDE is reporting a crash in CL.exe.

The only error it's reporting is `error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 1073741855`. In addition to this, I'm getting a lot of warnings concerning `Microsoft.CppCommon.targets`. Lots of the errors are of the form "The 'x' attribute is not declared."

This might seem like a stupid question, but I cannot understand why it's doing this.

According to the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532457/program-and-debugger-quit-without-indication-of-problem), the error code means `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT`. It's not clear to me how this is relevant to what I'm doing.

I created an empty solution and put this code:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Just to see if the problem remains. It does.

Possibly Useful Information:

- Operating System: Windows 7
- IDE Build: 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

Questions:

- Why is this happening?
- What can I do to figure out what's going on?
- What can I do to fix the problem?
- Is the information present in this question sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by updating Visual Studio 2012.
This can be ignored. Sorry for wasting your time.

Note to self: Never ignore updates no matter how much little bandwidth you have. ;_;