# Unable to build my code using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. It was going fine until this morning when I try to build my code. It gave me this weird error:

```
C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms
\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets(147,5)
:error` MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 1073741855.
```

I have no idea why this error is occuring. I need help please.

I am using Window 7.

Comment: If you try "Rebuild all" do you still get the error? You got all updates installed have you?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199655/cl-exe-crashes-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes still facing that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1073741855 is 0x0x4000001f, and 0x1f is decimal 31, and 31 is `ERROR_GEN_FAILURE`.  In other words, something is hosed and VS isn't going to tell you what it is.

Go to *Control Panel/Programs and Features*, right click, *Uninstall/Change*, *Repair/Reinstall*.  If that doesn't fix the problem, I would uninstall VS completely and reinstall.

Comment: Gergory i go to that path there are lot of Microsoft visual studio 2010 ... I dnt know which one to uninstall and then re-install :-(

Comment: You want the one named "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium - ENU" (but depending on which version of VS you installed and which language you chose, "Premium" and "ENU" might be different).

Comment: Yeah i see that Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate ENU but when i try to Uninstall/Change a box appear and there is written "Suite Integration Toolkit Executable has stopped working" ... Now what is this :(

Comment: Wow, sounds like your VS installation is really messed up.  I would forcibly uninstall 2010 using the tool found here [http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall).

Comment: KK im gonna uninstall it. 
i wanna tell u 1 more thing wheni build my code a box appear and there is written "Microsoft C/C++ Compiler Driver has stopped working".

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking to avoid the (timely) process of uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio, a simple restart worked for me.  I have noticed this happens more often when I have multiple Visual Studio windows open.