# Restart a form that is disposed

Tags: c#, cefsharp

A parent form starts a child form that embeds the Chromium Embedded Framework through CEFSharp. The user has the ability to close the child form. The user can restart the child form. When that happens the application terminates.

```
if (debugForm == null || debugForm.IsDisposed)
{
  if (debugForm != null && debugForm.IsDisposed)
  {
     debugForm = null;
  }
  debugForm = new CEFdebugger();
  ....
}
```

When the form has been run once, closed and restarted the line

```
debugForm = new CEFdebugger();
```

causes the application to terminate. In the output window I have

```
... has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f)
```

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4532492/529273) this indicates I should enable debugging unmanaged code, but that doesn't seem to have helped.
In the FormClosing event for CEFdebugger I have added

```
private void CEFdebugger_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Cef.Shutdown();
    this.Controls.Remove(browser);
    browser = null;
}
```

That hasn't helped. The application just terminates.

Comment: you should not reopen the same form instance - you should create a new one.

Comment: Is `browser` a COM component?

Comment: BTW, you should never ever need to do `GC.Collect()` in your code. Why are you doing it?

Comment: @DanielA.White - Unless I'm missing it in the OP's code, he's not trying to reopen the same form instance.

Comment: @Enigmativity it was an attempt to fix the problem, and it made no difference so I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the statement

```
Cef.Shutdown();
```

in CEFdebugger_FormClosing. By commenting it out and testing Cef.IsInitialized in the form constructor the problem was resolved.

Comment: How are we to know what `Cef.Shutdown();` does? This is where you need to make sure you post a [mcve] when asking a question.

Comment: Limitation of the `CEF` framework means you can only `Initialize` and `Shutdown` once.