# .NET application exits without exception 0x4000001f

Tags: c#, .net, crash

The application exits with:

> The program '[12868] AppName.vshost.exe' has exited with code 1073741855 (0x4000001f).

Below Code:

Call `Export()` twice after each other: crash with above logging
Call the contents of `Export()` inside `Export()` twice (the inner scope), and it doesn't crash.

This is reproducible, I have no idea where to start.

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Enable(false);

    statusbar.Message = "Exporting...";

    Task t = new Task(Export);
    t.ContinueWith(ExportEnd);
    t.Start();
}

private void Export()
{
    {
        PBNSectionDictionary source = ctrlSectionSelection.SectionSelection.SelectSections;
        PBNSectionDictionary dict = new PBNSectionDictionary();
        foreach (string sectionType in source.Keys)
        {
            if (source[sectionType] != null)
            {
                dict[sectionType] = collector.ReadFullSection(source[sectionType]);
            }
        }
        PBNFMV.Export.PBNExport export = new PBNFMV.Export.PBNExport(new Lms.Custom.Files.AdvancedFileLocator(Constants.NAME), dict, manager);
        export.Export();
        dict.Dispose();
    }
}

private void ExportEnd(Task t)
{
    Enable(true);

    statusbar.Message = "Export done";
}
```

Event log:

> Faulting application name: PBNFMV.exe, version: 16.2.0.0, time stamp: 0x58aeadf2
>   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23569, time stamp: 0x57f7bb79
>   Exception code: 0xc0000374
>   Fault offset: 0x000ce8fb
>   Faulting process id: 0xbd4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d28db92a6d6c1e
>   Faulting application path: C:\APPPATH\source\PBNFMV\bin\Debug\PBNFMV.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id: 72f988f9-f9ac-11e6-8d91-000acd1f71fd

Exception settings completely enabled:

C++ exceptions
common language runtime exceptions
gpu memory access exceptions
managed debugging assitants
win32 exceptions

Comment: Check the event viewer for any errors

Comment: have you checked exception setting of visual studio?

Comment: Is this the only entry in the event viewer? should be another one at least

Comment: 0xc0000374 is a very serious mishap, the operating system can't reasonably allow a program to continue with a corrupted heap.  You've got some digging to do, calling in the help of whomever wrote that native code is pretty important.  You cannot get this kind of help here.

Comment: This could be a duplicate for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532457/program-and-debugger-quit-without-indication-of-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved.

Hence: very strange.

It was due to construction of an object further (!) in code execution, which made things crash (because of a bad implementation in a library).

The strange part is why that object was already instantiated, i believe some optimalisation in the .net runtime.

Apologies

Comment: To Admin: if you want, you can delete this thread as it doesn't help anyone.